# Minimum Coin Change (Infinite, Unbound) Print the values

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, minimum, knapsack-problem, coin-change

The following function gets the minimum number of coins that should sum up or cover an amount.
for example: If I have coins: [6,11] and I need minimum coins to get 13
then the answer should be 2 (which 11, 6) and these are the minimum number of coins.

now I need to print the actual coins that made up this answer.

```
    private int minCapacity(int capacity[], int total, Map<Integer, Integer> map)
{
    // base case 
    if (total<= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //if map contains the result means we calculated it before. Lets return that value.
    if (map.containsKey(total))
    {
        return map.get(total);
    }

    // Initialize result 
    int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity.length; i++)
    {
        //allResults.add(capacity[i]);
        int subRes = minCapacity(capacity, total- capacity[i], map);
        System.out.println("total : " + subRes + ", staff: " + capacity[i]);
        //if val we get from picking coins[i] as first coin for current total is less
        // than value found so far make it minimum.

        if (subRes < res)
        {
            res = subRes;
            coinsRes.put(total, capacity[i]);
        }

    }
    res = (res == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? res : res + 1;

    //memoize the minimum for current total.
    map.put(total, res);
    return res;
}
```

> This is the output:
>
> total: 1 -> Capacity:6 total: 18 -> Capacity:11 total: 2 -> Capacity:6
>   total: 6 -> Capacity:6 total: 7 -> Capacity:11 total: 24 -> Capacity:6
>   total: 12 -> Capacity:6 Total: 13 -> Capacity:6

Now the formula should be to get the denominations is to:
Loop to: Max(total) - Capacity(total) till result is less than or equal Zero.

Denominations are: capacity(total) for each

Comment: This makes no sense to me. You've tagged this as "knapsack problem" and "coin change" and "dynamic programming"; but since you're OK with going over-target (11 + 6 > 13), you don't need any of that stuff. Just find the highest-denomination coin, and use as many of it are needed. No other coins are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Remember what item `capacity[i]` or index `i` gives the best `subres`

Store it in additional field of the map.

At the end unwind the best sequence from the map.

Comment: How to unwind the best sequence. Could you please give a snippet about your answer for more clarification. Many Thanks

Comment: You final result map entry `map.get(sum);` contains number of coins (`res`) and the last coin to reach this result (`coin`). Now go to `sum-coin` entry and repeat until 0

Comment: I tried to applied what you suggested ( Thank you ), but it leads me to wrong answer. ( Correct my code if im wrong)



 if (subRes < res)
            {
                res = subRes;
                coinsRes.put((res + 1), capacity[i]);
            }

I will edit it in the post code for more readable snippet

(Many Thanks for your support. Really Appreciate it )

Comment: capacity[i] value should correspond to total key, not to res

Comment: I updated the post. Correct me if Iam wrong or confirm it please.

Comment: Yes, it look more correct now. While I am not sure how do you handle sums higher than required